# How do I print information about an array out to the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have an array, and I want to print out various different elements to the console without using variables and such, how would that look like?

```
  function arrayDisplay(array) {
  array.length;
  array[0];
  array[array.length - 1];
}
console.log(arrayDisplay(["a", "b", "c"]));
```

Comment: you can use `console.log()` inside the function (ie: `console.log(array.length, array[0], ...)`). If you do that then you won't need to `console.log()` the function call as it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Your function needs to return the values you want to log

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`console.table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Console/table) to have a nicely-formatted table representing arrays, objects (and even nested structures of objects and arrays). It will not display the array's length, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it in a for loop:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
console.log("value " +i +" is: " array[i]);
}
```